# What was the first game to include a crafting system for non-critical in game items?

Tags: gaming-history

What was the first video game that allowed you to collect components or materials that had no intrinsic use by themselves, and then combine them into useful in game items such as weapons or food?

I'm specifically distinguishing between consumable items that make the game easier, as opposed to items that are essential for game play, such as un-skippable quest items that must be crafted in order to complete the game.

Comment: Ultima III: Exodus (1983) could be the answer, but I can't find any proof

Comment: What platform was it on?

Comment: Amiga, Atari, MS-DOS, NES...

Comment: Which one had the save first, I'm pretty sure that the NES was battery backup only.

Comment: It was originally developed for Apple II. This is the crafting question btw :)